# How to change the marker style on hover in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

When I hover over a marker in a chart, how can I remove the larger opaque circle behind the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halo can be adjusted using options described in Highcharts API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.states.hover.halo

Example:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        halo: {
                            size: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gujbp7qw/